# What probability distribution can be described as y ~ X * Exp(1)

Tags: distributions, exponential-distribution

The green dots show the product of X and the exponential distribution with rate 1.  It looks like it should be some simple probability distribution but I can't figure out what it is!

Can you tell me what distribution the green dots follow?

[image]

Comment: You compel your readers to guess what you need, because "product of X and the exponential distribution" makes no sense and has multiple interpretations.  Could edit this post to clarify what you mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you mean that the green plot is the function $f(x):=xe^{-x}$, then $f$ is the density of a [Gamma distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_distribution) with shape parameter 2 and scale parameter 1 (equivalently, rate parameter 1).